# How long does it take for Android market count of installations to update?

Tags: android

I can't find anything that says how long this is taking to update. I published an app, it's available and up there. When I go to my developer console on google play, it says it has 0 downloads. I know that's not true as i'm getting a few bug reports, and I also downloaded it on a couple of my own devices.
Do you know roughly how long this would take to update? Does anyone know from experience?
It's for my dissertation so i could really do with some numbers to be fairly time accurate.

Thanks,

Comment: Before they changed the statistics view there was a disclaimer that the stats were updated once a day, don't know if it still applies though.

Comment: Yes i have been seeing it daily and its updated daily and but not according to  your TimeZone (I guess from somewhere in U.S.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the 'Statistics' link for an app in your **Android Developer Console**, at the bottom of the statistics page, you can see

> Application statistics are updated daily.

What I have seen is that the update happens at around 12:00 hrs UTC. The time is not constant, there is a variance of several minutes.