# How to see the number of downloads for Android app in other country?

Tags: android, google-play, region

I just uploaded an app on google play at US. I have friends in Japan says that he downloaded my app and leave some comments. But I can't see that in my Developer Controller. Still 0 downloads, no comments on my google play page is US. Is there a way to see the google play in other country, and get the number of downloads in other country? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statistics are updated on a daily basis.  (Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10350312/1321873)) You should be able to see the download count within 24 hours of publishing the app. The **Android Developer Console** statistics page will show all the details about the application including the country-wise download count.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for the result